# Who receives shame in 1 Corinthians 11:4?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, textual-criticism, grammar

**1 Corinthians 11:3 [Khabouris Codex](http://dukhrana.com/peshitta/analyze_verse.php?verse=1Corinthians+11:3&font=Estrangelo+Edessa&size=150%&source=khabouris)**

> ܨܒܐ  ܐܢܐ  ܕܝܢ  ܕܬܕܥܘܢ  ܕܟܠ  ܓܒܪ  ܪܫܗ  ܡܫܝܚܐ  ܗܘ  ܘܪܫܗ  ܕܐܢܬܬܐ  ܓܒܪܐ  ܗܘ  ܘܪܫܗ  ܕܡܫܝܚܐ  ܐܠܗܐ  ܗܘ

**Build 1 (What I find from real life)**

> But I will understand of every man's head tis Christ, of woman's head tis man, and of Christ's tis Aloha.

**Build 2 (What I find from the Greek translation)**

> But I will understand Christ tis head of every man, man tis head of woman, and Aloha tis of Christ.

**1 Corinthians 11:4 [Khabouris Codex](http://dukhrana.com/peshitta/analyze_verse.php?verse=1Corinthians+11:4&font=Estrangelo+Edessa&size=150%&source=khabouris)**

> ܟܠ   ܓܒܪܐ   ܕܡܨܠܐ   ܐܘ   ܡܬܢܒܐ   ܟܕ   ܡܟܣܝ   ܪܫܗ   ܡܒܗܬ    ܪܫܗ

- (ܟܠ) all, every, whole, entirely
- (ܓܒܪܐ) man, husband, person
- (ܕܡܨܠܐ) incline toward, heed, pray
- (ܐܘ) O!, Oh!, or, else, rather than
- (ܡܬܢܒܐ) prophesy
- (ܟܕ) when, while
- (ܡܟܣܝ) cover, conceal, hide
- (ܪܫܗ) head, beginning, chiefs
- (ܡܒܗܬ) ashamed, shame
- (ܪܫܗ) head, beginning, chiefs

It appears that this word ܡܟܣܝ can mean (cover, conceal, hide)

**Build 1**

> Every man praying or prophesying when covering head shames head.

**Build 2**

> Every man praying or prophesying when concealing head shames head.

**Build 3**

> Every man praying or prophesying when hiding head shames head.

### Question

Who receives shame in 1 Corinthians 11:4? Aloha or Christ or man or another option.

Comment: These unicode charaters do not render on Chrome for me. Would pictured be possible instead? Or copying from another source? I usually don't have any trouble with Greek characters rendering.

Comment: @JamesShewey. The quotations are in Syriac, not Greek.

Comment: Using windows 8 and the browser called Firefox 46.0.1 the Syriac characters do render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Who receives shame in 1 Corinthians 11:4

I spent many years coming to this conclusion. Therefore, I give my opportunity of showing the work.

First lets start with the King James Version

> 1 Corinthians 11:4 KJV - "Every man praying or prophesying, having his head covered, dishonoureth his head."

After using the interlinearity at the [biblehub](https://biblehub.com/text/1_corinthians/11-4.htm) they showed how the translators represented the Greek word [κατὰ](https://biblehub.com/greek/2596.htm) as "[anything] on" and simply stated [κατὰ](https://biblehub.com/greek/2596.htm) does not mean that. "anything on" is the Greek [ἐπί](https://biblehub.com/greek/1909.htm).

[κατὰ](https://biblehub.com/greek/2596.htm) actually means literally "down" fulfilling the role as the preposition expressing relation. This left me with the phrase "down head" which opened many questions. the answer comes when 11:3 gets translated like this:

> 3 But I want y'all to realize because of every man the Template is the leading concern but the leading concern of the wife is the husband but the leading concern of the Template is Aloha.

This opens 11:4 to translate as:

> 4 Every man asking or planning down concerns of the Template has shamed himself.

### Conclusion

Everyone asking or making plans within the goals of the Template remains honorable.

Answer (score -2):

It  seems to me  the word for head can be compared to a mind, so if the mind of the woman (her husband) is uncovered (without guide) she shames her mind. If the mind (that is Messiah) of the man is covered (with alternative guide) he shames his mind).  I believe John 17 will support this (with emphasis on verses 21 and 22) and 1st Corinthians 2 with emphasis on verses 16. That is to say the man shames himself.

Comment: We can't [take for granted](https://faithbibleministriesblog.com/2012/07/06/the-heart-and-the-mind-what-the-biblical-word-heart-means/) that the head was the seat of consciousness in antiquity. Similarly, Comedian and singer-songwriter Mark Lowry had a comedy set about the seat of emotion being the bowels.

Comment: Hi friend my hope was to show that the Mind that is to say the innermost part, the heart or his understanding is the driving  force of his action and In the same way so is his head.  it seems that this way of thinking is not so ale

Comment: my hope was to show that the Mind the innermost part, the heart and the head are the driving force of mans action.  it seems that this way of thinking is not so alien to the Israelite. Rosh the Hebrew word that has been translated head has also been translated as chief principal beginning this should be essential to remind us that we could easily remove the possibility that Paul thought the driving force was applicable to the hear and head. Judge 11:11 Gilad is the head of the people Aloah both lead action from the midst and head of Isreal I want to help you gave me negative.

Comment: I hope to disassociate the question from the application of it to women all together. In this focus I hope to apply it only to the "shame" as to who it applies to for if a "man" if he covers his head or conceals his head or hides his head, whatever the true nature of this meaning of this concept defines. Neither of if it means to cover the head with a cloth, or if to hide his name, or to not say it out loud hiding the son of man, or to not say it out loud and should in the mind only, or if both from the mind and the word shining a light, but to who gets the shame.